# Elastic indeces stats show different document count

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticsearch index have around 23mln documents, but if I check with

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/_stats?pretty'
```

I see 7 times more documents

```
"primaries" : {
      "docs" : {
        "count" : 150292264,
        "deleted" : 16121164
      },
...
}
```

How is calculated these stats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for higher count is that `_stats` api also consider **nested documents**. I think you have [nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) in your mapping.

You can use [count api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) to get count of top level documents.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/_count?pretty'
```

will return 23 million docs.

As for the deleted documents, they represent the documents which have been either updated or deleted. When you update a document the previous one is marked deleted and new one is added since segments are immutable. These deleted documents occupy space on your disk until the next merge is called. You can read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/merge-process.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/lucenes-handling-of-deleted-documents)

Lastly, you could try to reclaim the disk space by calling [force merge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html) but it is very heavy operation and will block any new requests until it is completed.